# How to retrieve the total transferred and received bytes in a WireGuard(wireguard-apple) implementation using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, xcode, vpn, wireguard

I've been working on integrating the WireGuard-Apple project into my personal VPN project using Swift Package Manager. I have successfully implemented WireGuard and can enable and disable the tunnel using my PacketTunnelProvider class.

However, I'm not using the WireGuard-Apple UI and would like to add a small piece of code that retrieves the total transferred and received bytes. I've looked at the source code of the original WireGuard-Apple UI project, but I couldn't figure out how to implement this feature.

Has anyone added this functionality to their implementation and could provide guidance on how to do so?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I have searched through all the WireGuardKit functions but couldn't find any that provide the information I need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.